# How to center the layout of a particular collection about a point

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a graph with a cose-bilkent layout. I'm trying to enable the user to search for a particular collection of nodes, and then have the program run a concentric layout for only those in the collection in order to zoom/concentrate on the collection of interest. All works well, except that in the process of making these nodes concentric, they are all moved to the bottom right corner of the screen (at least relative to the other nodes in the graph).

Is there an option for any of the built-in layouts to center the nodes being 'layed out' about a particular location in the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

The option to "pin" a layout its through the use of the boundingBox layout option. Most (or all) layouts have this option.

You can try this:

```
let p = node.data(/* Your node position field */);

let l = nodes.layout({
    name: 'concentric',
    fit: false,
    //your animation and padding options
    boundingBox: {
      x1: p.x - 1,
      x2: p.x + 1,
      y1: p.y - 1,
      y2: p.y + 1
    },
    avoidOverlap: true,
    concentric: function( ele ){
      if( ele.same( node ) ){
        return 2;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    },
    levelWidth: function(){ return 1; },
});

l.run();
```

Adapted from this [example](http://www.wineandcheesemap.com/), that share some similarity with your problem. It places everything from the neighborhood of a node you select in a concentric layout, without moving the selected node, only the other nodes.

You can find its complete source code [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/wineandcheesemap).